# error when opening map in ViewNX and ViewNX-I

Tags: windows-10

I've reinstall win 10 and now ViewNX-i can't open the map tab and it pops this error message:

"Your computer may not be connected to the network..."

[image]

Anyone had this problem? It must be something with my windows. On another PC it works fine.

PS: Process monitor details[image: Process monitor details]

Comment: What server is it trying to use?

Comment: tried to connect to US server and then i set it to "Connect to automatically selected server / based to my ip" ans still not working